# Редирект на 404 страницу

Tags: php, http, редирект, header

В .htaccess прописал:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /views/error.html
```

В скрипте отправляю заголовок:

```
header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
exit();
```

Перенаправление не срабатывает.
Пробовал и так писать:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found', true, 404);
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
```

Не срабатывает всё равно. Может что-то дописать нужно ещё?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5914259/2110496 В общем, как я и говорил. php-скрипт найден, apache умывает руки

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53664/discussion-on-question-by-azhirov1991---404-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ErrorDocument` верно срабатывает, когда реально нет страницы. Передача заголовка лично у меня тоже верно сработала, и в целом должна верно срабатывать, если сервер и php верно настроены. Но при этом во втором пункте apache уже не собирается переадресацию какую-то делать, так как он не видит в этом смысла - `ErrorDocument` срабатывает именно что на реальное отсутствие страницы или отсутствие правил редиректа для запрошенного адреса, когда же страница просто отдает код 404 - это ее дело. Далее подразумевается, что нужно самому вывести нужное.

То есть либо заинклудить целиком страницу, лежащую по пути /views/error.html примерно таким кодом:

```
if (we_have_404) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found', true, 404);
    include "/views/error.html";
    exit();
}
```

дабы минимизировать повторяющийся код на сайте, либо выводить что-либо свое.

Comment: Написано логично) я понял. Спасибо)

Comment: @azhirov1991 ага. Есть еще вариант и с Location в заголовке скрипта - он будет переадресовывать на страницу `views/error.html`, но это будет лишним временем ожидания для посетителя, так как тогда у нас сначала будет ответ от сервера с кодом `302`, после которого он попадет уже на страницу ошибки. При этом кстати в странице ошибки нужно будет первым делом вывести заголовок `404`, так как она его получает автоматически только в том случае, если на нее мы попали с помощью директивы сервера `ErrorDocument`